# Getting a big white space gap

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

Im trying to make a scrollbar in my content div insted of a scrollbar for the whole window. But it makes a huge white space in the content box and i cant figure out why. Can anyone take a look and see if they can find out why?

Here is my site: [www.rajohan.no/index.php?page=movie&category=comming](http://www.rajohan.no/index.php?page=movie&category=comming)

Also the scrollbar is going under the footer, is there anyway i can make it stop at the footer start?

Im using overflow: hidden; in the body and then overflow-y: auto; in my content div

Here is my jQuery script to see if a scrollbar is needed

```
// Check if content_box need a scrollbar
function calculateDivHeight() {
  $("#content_box").height(window.innerHeight);
}
$(window).resize(function () {
  calculateDivHeight();
});
```

Comment: You have a `min-height: 100%;` in your `.content-size` div. Remove that and we are fine.

Comment: Thanks! that fixed the white space problems :) Is there a way to make the scrollbar and the content of the div to not go under the footer? Some of the content is hidden under the footer the way it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of your element id 'content_box' is become 100% of the page and you set the css position of your footer to fixed. Thats why it happens because fotter comes before the contentbox. You my try set height of the content_box 75vh and 20vh to footer and 5vh to header which lets them all to fit into screen and use no fixed fotter.